# A conjecture on fixed points for operations in certain permutation subgroups.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Fix an odd integer $m$ that is not divisible by three. Choose the elements $\sigma, \tau \in S_m$ (from the symmetric group on $m$ elements) that satisfy the following relationships (in $\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$):

$\sigma(0) = 1/2$ 
$\tau(0) = 0$ 
$\sigma(i+2) = \sigma(i) + 3$
$\tau(i+2) = \tau(i) + 1$

Example: Take $m = 5$. Then, $\sigma = (1 \; 2) (3 \; 5)$ and $\tau = (1 \; 3 \; 4 \; 2)$, in cyclic notation.

Now, for a binary string, read across the string, repeatedly applying $\sigma$ for each '1' and $\tau$ for each '0'. (I choose to read left to right and apply on the left, but it doesn't really matter for the question.)

Example: The string '001011' corresponds to the element $\sigma \sigma \tau \sigma \tau \tau $, which equals $(1 \; 2 \; 5 \; 4)$ if $m = 5$. Notice that this element has the fixed point $3$. The string '001' corresponds to the element $\sigma \tau \tau$, which equals $(1 \; 4 \; 2 \; 5 \; 3)$ if $m = 5$. Notice that this element has no fixed point.

**Question**: For every string $s$ with exactly $k > 2$ ones and of length $n = \lceil k \log_2 3 \rceil$, is there an $m$ (with $2 \nmid m$ and $3 \nmid m$) such that the element in $S_m$ corresponding to the string $s$ (or at least a cyclic permutation of $s$) has no fixed points?

Computer experimentation suggests this statement might be true. Any thoughts on how this conjecture might be approached?

Edit: Here is a list of the smallest values of $m$ such that *every* string with exactly $k$ ones and of length $n = \lceil k \log_2 3 \rceil$ corresponds to an element with no fixed point in some $S_{m'}$ with $m' \leq m$.

$k = 3, m = 5$ 
$k = 4, m = 47$ 
$k = 5, m = 13$ 
$k = 6, m = 59$ 
$k = 7, m = 83$ 
$k = 8, m = 233$ 
$k = 9, m = 2617$ 
$k = 10, m = 499$ 
$k = 11, m = 7727$

Edit: I realized that taking $m = 2^n - 3^k$ makes it work for any string $s$ of length $n$ with exactly $k$ ones (which when proved will imply the conjecture). Furthermore, if $\rho$ is the element of $S_m$ corresponding to $s$, then, since $\rho(i + 2^n) = \rho(i) + 3^k$ (from definitions of $\sigma$ and $\tau$), it follows that $\rho$ has a fixed point if and only if it is the identity (since $2^n \equiv 3^k \pmod{2^n-3^k}$ trivially), so it suffices to show that any combination of $k$ $\sigma$'s and $n-k$ $\tau$'s is *not* the identity in $S_m$, which might be related to the fact that $2^n - 3^k$ grows roughly like $3^k$.

Comment: You can also write $\sigma(i) = (3i_1)/2$ and $\tau(i) = i/2$ (both modulo $m$) directly, without needing a recusrive definition.

Comment: The recursive definition helps obscure the nature of the origin of the problem, which helps prevent people from willfully disregarding the question.

Comment: Regardless of whether I believe the claim in your comment, I question any strategy of seeking help from volunteers that includes deliberately obfuscating the question one wants help with.

Comment: I'm not obfuscating the question, only the motivation. There's no reason the other definition should be any more clear in attempting to answer the question posed.

Comment: Also, to be clear to others, it's $\sigma(i) = (3i + 1)/2$. There was a typo where an underscore was entered instead of a plus sign.